# How to test whether two time series are statistically different?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing

Every quarter, we ask around 2500 companies  about their business situation. The possible answers  are good (+1), normal (0) or bad (-1). The answers are, then, aggregated to an index (series_1) (The index corresponds to the simple arithmetic mean of all answers multiplied by a factor of 100). In additon, we calculated the same index for a subsector (series_2).

[image]

What I am trying to find out is **which test I can use to test whether the two time series are statiscally different from each other**.

Although I googled a lot, I could not find a statistical test to answer my question. So, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This post seems very similar to what you are looking for... https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19103/how-to-statistically-compare-two-time-series

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** *I am myself [somewhat confused](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/454447/169343) regarding time series, but in your case I don't think time-seriesness is a relevant feature.*

If you plot your data not as two curves over time, but as a scatter plot, with values of one series on the $x$-axis and the corresponding (in time) values of the other on the $y$-axis, the points should lie more-or-less on a straight line: Where series 1 has a high value, series 2 is also high, and vice versa.

You are actually asking whether the two series measure the same "thing" (the same sentiment about the business situation). You can test that with [Intraclass correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation).

Comment: Thanks for the disclaimer, Igor. These explanationa helped a lot. I wasn't aware of this.